# How to scale down the desktop?

Tags: release-freya, desktop

When I installed Freya on a 22" Screen, everything was fine. But when I plug the PC in a 40" TV, the desktop is upscaled to 200%. The screen resolution is correctly 1920x1080 but because of the upscaling it looks more like 960x540.

When I rescale it with `xrandr --output DFP2 --scale 2x2` the screen looks fine, but the mouse cursor is confined to the top left quarter of the screen.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: My answer is pretty much a shot in the dark as this problem is probably hard to debug...

Answer (score 11):

## dconf-editor

(Install dconf-editor by typing `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor` in the command line.)

Open dconf-editor and navigate to `org.gnome.desktop.interface` and check the value of `scaling-factor`. It is probably set to `2` (which is for high density displays) and you should change it to `1`. For now, non-integer values will not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "as of now"? A recent update to `dconf` or `Gala` or what?

Comment: It was set to 0, probably auto scaling. Changing it to 1 worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: @Gan Please accept an answer if the answer solved your problem. Thanks

Comment: @Gabriel Mistake on my part. I don't think floating numbers were ever supported.

Comment: 0 uses the default for the display btw. I was fiddling with numbers, then set it back to 0 and some windows weren't changing, but after a reboot (still set at 0), everything looks good.

Answer (score 5):

### Terminal

To solve your problem without installing extra software:

- Open Terminal
- to get your scaling factor
  `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor`
- to set your scaling factor
  `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 1`